# Python: Calculate factorial of a non-integral number

Tags: python, floating-point, factorial

I'm wondering if there's a speedy, Pythonic way to calculate factorials of non-integral numbers (e.g., 3.4)? Of course, the bult-in `factorial()` function in the `Math` module is available, but it only works for integrals (I don't care about negative numbers here).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'd want to use [`math.gamma(x)`.](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/math.html#math.gamma)

The [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) is an extension of the factorial function to real numbers.

Note that the function is shifted by 1 when compared to the factorial function. So `math.factorial(n)` is `math.gamma(n + 1)`.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2.7 or 3.2, you can use `math.gamma(x + 1)`.  In older versions, you'd need some external library like SciPy.