# How to work around int too long to convert to float error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to determine the first 10 digit prime number in consecutive digits of e, and therefore want to calculate e to an arbitrary number of decimal points.  This is the code I have, but when I enter 1000 for example, it can't convert the factorial into a float as it's too big:

```
import math

def calculate_e(n):
    e_real=0.0
    e_test=0.0
    accurate=False
    term=1 
    while accurate==False:
        e_real=sum(1 / float(math.factorial(i)) for i in range(term))
        if (e_real-e_test)<n:
            accurate=True
        else:
            accurate=False
        term+=1
        e_test=e_real
    return e_real

a=input("Enter accuracy: ")+1
b=10**(-a)
e=round(calculate_e(b),a)
print e
```

Also, something else I was having trouble with is printing that number of digits without rounding.  Say I want to see the first 3 digits of e, I want it to output 271, not 272.  The best I've been able to come up with is just making it 1 decimal more accurate and rounding it to one more decimal.

Comment: You could look at the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module, though you will take a performance hit (if that is important to you).

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10056797

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE While it is true that the OP probably wants to use the function suggested in the answer to that question, I am not sure it is a duplicate because this question is about getting around the limitations of floats, not about calculation the factorial of a float.

Comment: @SethMMorton Cheers, that's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.  Performance is no compromise if it allows the thing to actually work haha.  This is kind of leaning off topic, but how come the decimal can deal with arbitrarily big integers, when floats can't?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't matter that the factorial gets too big. You have a more important problem way earlier:

```
>>> import math
>>> for term in range(30):
        e_real = sum(1 / float(math.factorial(i)) for i in range(term))
        print '%2d %.60f' % (term, e_real)

 0 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 1 1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 2 2.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 3 2.500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 4 2.666666666666666518636930049979127943515777587890625000000000
 5 2.708333333333333037273860099958255887031555175781250000000000
 6 2.716666666666666341001246109954081475734710693359375000000000
 7 2.718055555555555447000415369984693825244903564453125000000000
 8 2.718253968253968366752815200015902519226074218750000000000000
 9 2.718278769841270037233016410027630627155303955078125000000000
10 2.718281525573192247691167722223326563835144042968750000000000
11 2.718281801146384513145903838449157774448394775390625000000000
12 2.718281826198492900914516212651506066322326660156250000000000
13 2.718281828286168710917536373017355799674987792968750000000000
14 2.718281828446759362805096316151320934295654296875000000000000
15 2.718281828458230187095523433526977896690368652343750000000000
16 2.718281828458994908714885241352021694183349609375000000000000
17 2.718281828459042870349549048114567995071411132812500000000000
18 2.718281828459045534884808148490265011787414550781250000000000
19 2.718281828459045534884808148490265011787414550781250000000000
20 2.718281828459045534884808148490265011787414550781250000000000
21 2.718281828459045534884808148490265011787414550781250000000000
22 2.718281828459045534884808148490265011787414550781250000000000
23 2.718281828459045534884808148490265011787414550781250000000000
24 2.718281828459045534884808148490265011787414550781250000000000
25 2.718281828459045534884808148490265011787414550781250000000000
26 2.718281828459045534884808148490265011787414550781250000000000
27 2.718281828459045534884808148490265011787414550781250000000000
28 2.718281828459045534884808148490265011787414550781250000000000
29 2.718281828459045534884808148490265011787414550781250000000000
```

These are the exact values computed in `e_real`. You can see that when `term` becomes 18 or larger, your `e_real` doesn't change anymore. Floats simply don't have the capacity to store anywhere near 1000 significant digits.

As SethMMorton said, check out the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module. That can fix both of your issues.

Comment: Cheers.  Yeah, I didn't think about that either.  I'm still really new, so I guess I didn't fully understand what a float was and the difference between that and a decimal.  I asked this to SethMMorton as well, but how is it that decimals are somehow capable of dealing with arbitrarily large integers but floats aren't?

Comment: @user7389469 Because floats are (typically) the standard 64-bit floats while decimals are implemented as an "array of digits" (something like that) where you can specify the size.